# Python Flask application getting OPTIONS instead of POST

Tags: python, json, flask

I have a python Flask listener waiting on port 8080. I expect another process to make a series of POST's to this port.The code for listener is as follows.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2
from __future__ import print_function
from flask import Flask, request
from werkzeug import secure_filename
from datetime import datetime
import os, traceback, sys 
import zlib
import ssl 
import json
import os
import base64

app = Flask('__name__')

@app.route('/',methods=['GET','POST','OPTIONS'])                                                                                                                                         
def recive_fe_events():
    try:
        data = request.get_data()

        if request.content_length < 20000 and request.content_length != 0:
            filename = 'out/{0}.json'.format(str(datetime.now()))
            with open(filename, 'w') as f:
                 f.write(data)

            print('Wrote', filename)
        else:
            print("Request too long", request.content_length)
            content = '{{"status": 413, "content_length": {0}, "content": "{1}"}}'.format(request.content_length, data)
            return content, 413 
    except:
        traceback.print_exc()
        return None, status.HTTP_500_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR

    return '{"status": 200}\n'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0',debug=False,port=8080)
```

However whenever I try to trigger an event to be pushed to the above listener.It seems that I am getting `OPTIONS` instead of `POST`.

```
192.168.129.75 - - [20/May/2015 14:33:45] "OPTIONS / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
192.168.129.75 - - [20/May/2015 14:33:45] "OPTIONS / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
192.168.129.75 - - [20/May/2015 14:33:51] "OPTIONS / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
192.168.129.75 - - [20/May/2015 14:33:51] "OPTIONS / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```

I read in the flask documentation. (Starting with Flask 0.6, OPTIONS is implicitly added and handled by the standard request handling.)

Why am I seeing `OPTIONS` when I expect `POST`.It seems that `POST` seems to be missing for some reason.I have captured the traffic while the POST is happening usuing tcpdump and analyzed using wireshark.The relevant portion of the trace is attached here.
[image: Wireshark decode output]

It does seem to me that the source trying to do the POST is encrypting the data using SSL.Is my understanding correct?

Comment: Where's your client code?

Comment: it is confidential.I can't POST that here.

Comment: If you can't post your client code (even the part with the request), try to make a curl request to your server. If it sends a POST request, the problem is in your client.

Comment: I can send a curl request and that does work.Also please see updated question above.

Comment: Do you have any SSL settings defined somewhere else? Can you do the job with the `debug=True`?

Comment: @sobolevn - I don't have SSL defined anywher in my listener. But I am not very sure about the sender itself. From the wireshark dump can we conclude that the sender is encrypting the data?

Comment: There is something defentily wrong with it. What client do you use?

Comment: @sobolevn - I can't disclose client information - sorry

Comment: The flask application most likely isn't the problem. If you can send a curl with a post then you know the application accepts posts. If you can't post any of your client code you're probably SOL.

Answer (score 2):

Unless you are going to explicitly deal with the `OPTIONS` method, don't put it in your methods.

Try this instead:

```
@app.route('/',methods=['GET','POST'])
```

Comment: Your problem isn't that you get OPTIONS, your problem is that you *aren't* getting POST. Whether you handle OPTIONS on your own or whether Flask handles it for you, something about your OPTIONS response isn't pleasing to your client. Try sniffing the traffic with, for example, wireshark and see what might be off about your OPTIONS. Also, try to instrument your client to see what he doesn't like about the OPTIONS response.

Comment: hi, can you please link some documentation regarding "Whether you handle OPTIONS on your own or whether Flask handles it for you" i.e. where can I find some docs on how Flask handles OPTIONS for you by default? Thanks